# Tomcat Manager Application - Too many sessions

Tags: session, tomcat, tomcat6

When I check my `Tomcat` Application Manager, I see that I have too many sessions (over 4600):

[image: Too many sessions]

Why is that so ? Can this be linked to a deployed application or is it the fact that it has been up for a long time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons for this, some more exotic than others. Some of them:

- you really have a lot of users coming to your site
- your app ran out of memory and the thread which invalidates sessions has died
- you've been hit by a search engine crawler or DDOSed (not very likely)
- you have some sort of monitoring enabled which is done via HTTP and the sessions are not discarded

Have you looked at the list of these sessions? Do they have similar idle times? What pages are being hit? What do the HTTP logs say? (Google) Analytics?

The fact that the app has been online for a long time has no correlation to the session count. Tomcat invalidates these sessions on a regular basis.

In order to get the **most precise** answer do a memory dump and analyze it using the profiler.

Comment: `you have some sort of monitoring enabled which is done via HTTP and the sessions are not discarded` this is the most likely cause as I use a `comet` service for push notifications.. do i need to programatically remove the sessions or is it, as you suggester, Tomcat run out of memory and the sessions are not valid ?

Comment: If your comet request does not require sessions, simply add `session.invalidate()` at the end of your servlet call or if you can't do it for whatever reason, add a filter which does that.

Comment: I stopped all my running applications (I left only `/`,  `/host-manager` and  `/manager` context paths), but i still have 6000+ sessions (and counting). So it's not an application problem. The sessions have no attribute and have 30min timeout each.

Comment: tomcat uses 21% memory and almost no cpu at all.. (i just restarted it).. what can the problem be ? thanks

Comment: Have you done the memory dump? This is the only thing capable of giving sure answers.

Comment: How can I do that? What tools do I need ?

Comment: [jmap -dump:format=b,file=/path/to/your/file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) and then any profiler, e.g. YourKit or JConsole.